# "session has expired" error - after clicking a button with webdriver in IE8

Tags: java, window, webdriver

After clicking a button in my application with webdriver, it gives me “sorry..your session has been expired” in IE8 and i am unable to proceed. But I am able to do it manually.

Now to proceed with webdriver automation i have to login into my application manually first, then it doesnt give me that session expired error.

Problem is my application only works on IE. This issue is a showstopper now.

Now i am confused, is this an IE issue (some cookie handling) or webdriver provides some support for session or cookie handling?

Comment: When testing it manually, you are using IE8 right? What version of Selenium? What version of the IE Driver?

Comment: @Arran:yes while testing manually i am using IE8.
My selenium version is: selenium-java-2.24.1
and IEdriver version: IEDriverServer_Win32_2.25.3

As i am using 32 bit system(windows XP).
if u need more info please lemme know.
Thanks

Comment: @Arran:As per selenium docs here in  http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver  I was trying to set "protected mode settings" but first thing its not mentioned there for Window xp and i am using Window XP.The second thing is on my machine i am not able to see any check box under tools-->internetOptions-->security.I think may be due to my office's security reasons.Now i am stuck how to do it.Please help me.